# Grabbing strings with his own entitle from a sentences by php

Tags: php

```
Storyline : A cryptic phone call sets off a dangerous game of risks for Elliot, a 
down-on-his luck salesman. Company : BDSE Language : English Country : USA Awards : 2 
nominations Certification : Germany:16 | UK:15 | USA:R Color : Color Rating 
: 6.3 Runtime : 93 min
```

From these above sentences I want echo every particular entitle with its detail at different places at my page. How to do it please?

So for example, I want to display above sentences like as:

```
Storyline : A cryptic phone call sets off a dangerous game of risks for Elliot, a down-on-his luck salesman. 

Company : BDSE 
Language : English 
Country : USA 
Awards : 2 nominations 
Certification : Germany:16 | UK:15 | USA:R 
Color : Color 

Rating : 6.3 
Runtime : 93 min
```

Comment: Are the nine categories consistent?

Comment: Categories are variable sir.

Comment: I think you're going to have a hard time then. There is nothing consistent about this data structure.

Comment: Try [regexp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). Apart from Certification, it should be straightforward. If you can resolve it , you are wecome to answer the question yourself. Otherwise update the question with what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Comment: If I keep these nine categories consistent, how to get above result please?

Comment: You could regex it pretty easily if you know the nine categories and their order.

Comment: I now about regex, not have enough practice. Can you do more or any guideline please?

Comment: Assuming the categories will never be in the content...https://regex101.com/r/kC9pF4/1

Comment: Maybe even: https://eval.in/639737 or you could even capture the category and get rid of named groups, that'd probably be easier.

Comment: have you any influence on the source of that data? To adjust agreed-on separator(between catogories)

Comment: @ chris85 Thank you sir, let me see...